# InvalidOperationException in Razor View with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to build a flashcard application to learn MVC4.  A Set contains Cards, and a Card contains Sides (to facilitate one or many-sided cards).

I have the following viewModel for Card Creation:

```
public class CreateCardViewModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int SetId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ICollection<Side> Sides { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsReady { get; set; }

    }
```

And the following actions defined for Create:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(int setId)
        {
            var model = new CreateCardViewModel();

            // attach card to current set
            model.SetId = setId;

            // create a new Side
            var side = new Side() {Content = "Blank Side"};

            // Add this to the model's Collection
            model.Sides = new Collection<Side> { side };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateCardViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var set = _db.Sets.Single(s => s.SetId == viewModel.SetId);
                var card = new Card {Sides = viewModel.Sides};

                set.Cards.Add(card);

                _db.Save();
            }
            return View(viewModel);


        }
```

In the view, I'm trying to start by displaying the Side that I created in the Controller, and allowing the user to edit it.  I get "InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions." when I try to run with the following markup in the view:

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CreateCardViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SetId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SetId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SetId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsReady)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsReady)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsReady)
        </div>


        // OFFENDING CODE
        @foreach (var side in Model.Sides)
             {
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sides.ElementAt(side.SideId))
             }

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

How can I let the user edit the existing Side when creating a card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ElementAt()`, just use the normal `[]` index operator:

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sides[side.SideId])`

Comment: I tried this and I get an error that says "cannot apply indexing to an expression of type ICollection.

Comment: Are you able to use an IList instead?